# How come when I ask for user input for an sql query, my result not showing?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
package jdbc;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;  
class driver{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/entries","root","");  
//here sonoo is database name, root is username and password  
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select word from entries where word LIKE '%_apple'"); 
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What rhymes with apple?");
boolean set = true;
String info = scan.next();
while(rs.next() && set)
{
if(rs.getString("word").equals(info))
System.out.println("success");

}
con.close();  

}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
}  
}
```

Above is code to ask the user what word rhymes with apple.  I am searching a sql database of English dictionary.  Why is it that Success is not being printed?

Comment: The above code finds words that have end with _apple

Comment: You're looking for natural language processing which is something totally different. https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=natural%20language%20processing%20rhyme

Answer (score 1):

The above code finds words that have end with '_apple'.

It will never find words that rhyme.

You're looking for natural language processing which is something totally different. Checkout https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=natural%20language%20processing%20rhyme

Comment: If i type in Grapple though it should give me success right.

Comment: No. Like finds text within text.